# Is the "Great Wave off Kanagawa" a political piece?

Tags: painting

I like the painting "The Great Wave of Kanagawa".
[image: A wave in the foreground; Mt Fuji in the background. Three boats bear people bowing to the wave.]

One of the things I recently noticed was that there are 3 boats, and all the people in the boats are bowing to the wave. The wave looks big enough to wash away Mt. Fuji.

Humans bowing along with the cultural significance of Mt. Fuji suggests this had a political message relevant to the artist at the time of painting. For sponsorship, sometimes artists must appeal to the great families, the Medici of their era and geography.  If you look at Dante's "Inferno" it names names and people and is, I think, clearly and strongly a political piece of the time.

Why I think/guess there is a political message encoded in the art:

- The wave is 5x taller than the mountain.  That big of a difference is cognitively significant.
- There are 3 boats with people face-down in them, bowing in fear or death.  These are emotionally powerful messages for humans.
- Mount Fuji is in the background.  The mount is culturally significant, and was so for up to a thousand years before the painting was made.
- Mount Fuji is at the center of the figure, and is at the bottom-center of the "circle" of the waves.
- The "foam" of the waves are all about the same size, and are curved like dragon claws.  Real foam is multi-scale and multi-orientation.  This can be achieved artistically without the kind of uniformity used here.
- Two boats appear underwater, only one is above.
- There is a structural arch that appears at religious places on the deck of the non-sunk ship.

Is there any knowledge about a political meaning, given the context of the original creation, of the elements within this painting?  Is the inference of a political implication off base, and if so why?

**Update:**
This link
http://www.bbc.co.uk/ahistoryoftheworld/objects/MAPlqOEHRsmI1awIHQzRSQ

Attributes Christine Guth, School of Oriental and African Studies, University of London with this quote

> It is often argued that Japan was cut off from the world during this
> period, but that is not in fact the case there was an enormous
> enthusiasm for things exotic, for things from abroad during this
> period. Whether things from China or things from Europe. And one of
> the reasons that Hokusai’s Great Wave became such a success was that
> it was printed in an exotic new colour that had a saturate hue that
> was unknown until that time. And this colour was imported and was
> synthetic and is colour that we now know in English as Prussian blue
> or Berlin blue, and this says a lot about the way in which Japan was
> connected through trade to China and to the world beyond.

and Timothy Clark, curator, British Museum

> The eccentric composition of the print is a bravura display by Hokusai
> to show how he has digested supposedly 'rational' European-style
> perspective and made something much more dramatic and exciting out of
> it. When European artists and collectors began to discover and
> celebrate the print in the late nineteenth, they may well have been
> responding - consciously or unconsciously - to this
> European-influenced way of seeing that was deeply imbedded in the
> image.

So it speaks to printing vs. painting, the elements of European style as seen from Japan, and the printing technology itself.

While these speak to the artists intention to disrupt the internal establishment in a general sense, they do not necessarily point to or away from a particular meaning encoded in the elements of the image.

Comment: I know some arts-folks who are very aggressive about direct questions, and I wanted to avoid burning myself that way.  Apparently I went too far to the indirect.  There is an explicit question.  Can you please reopen it?  I wish you would have told me the problem before chopping the head off.  That feels unfriendly.

Comment: I don't want to change the topic.  Art history, and art criticism are essential.  Is there a forum to ask about the context and meaning of great historic works of art?  Is this about methods only, and not about evaluation or understanding of the roots of quality? https://www.smithsonianmag.com/travel/mount-fuji-endures-powerful-force-japan-180962782/

Comment: @Joachim - can you move my question there.  A brief review of on-topic doesn't give any red flags.

Comment: It has political implications [Prussian Blue](https://www.widewalls.ch/magazine/japanese-wave-painting-hokusai) is important , 
 and ["So for a very long time Japanese government officials, Japanese art historians were not happy about the attention that print culture garnered in the West and art historians or the cultured elite wanted Europeans and Americans to look at different kinds of things and not look at this as representative."](https://www.wnyc.org/story/180025-hokusais-the-great-wave/)

Comment: [The book by Christine Guth](https://www.degruyter.com/view/title/530783) looks like a great source if you can track it down.

Comment: Re "The wave is 5x taller than the mountain", no, it isn't. Ever hear of perspective?  For the rest,  Hokusai did many earlier paintings of waves.  The Great Wave one is part of his "Thirty-six Views of Mount Fuji", so it would be surprising if the mountain didn't appear in it:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thirty-six_Views_of_Mount_Fuji

Comment: @jamesqf - Perspective is an abstraction.  If I put a ruler on my copy of the picture, the trough-to-peak of the wave is literally about 5x higher than the mount.  The particular POV is an important part of the piece.  I'm not convinced that just because it was part of a series it becomes non-political.  There are plenty of political things that happen more than a single object at a time.

Comment: @EngrStudent: But if you do any halfway realistic drawing (or FTM photographs), distant objects are going to be drawn smaller than closer ones, just as in almost all the other views of Fuji in that series.   You seem to be going to considerable length to impute a political meaning to what seems to be artistic choices.

Comment: @jamesqf What about hierarchical perspective? There is no magic border between realism and abstraction that once crossed will rule out the symbolism behind compositional choices. The fact that the wave is huge in comparison to the boat has an unmistakable bearing on our reading of the picture - why is the notion of extrapolating that to the top of Mt. Fuji reaching? Moreover, the low perspective is remarkable even when compared to Hokusai's other works in the series.